# := or += when compiling Linux kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver

Tutorials for compiling the kernel module for Linux, use different syntax for the Makefile.

**[Example 1](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2013/01/16/compiling-kernel-modules-for-raspberry-pi.aspx)**

```
obj-m += rpi-pwm.o
```

**[Example 2](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux)**

```
obj-m := nothing.o
```

What are the differences, and is there a preferred way?

Comment: See [Gnu Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Variables) documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:=` would *set* the variable `obj-m` to `nothing.o`.  This implies that if `obj-m` was previously set then it would be replaced by `nothing.o`.

`+=` would *add* `rpi-pwm.o` to the variable `obj-m`.  If `obj-m` was previously set to `nothing.o`, then it'd become `nothing.o rpi-pwm.o`.

Saying

```
obj-m += rpi-pwm.o
```

is equivalent to saying

```
obj-m := $(obj-m) rpi-pwm.o
```